# Use sendgrid template instead of django-alluth template when confirming email

Tags: django, sendgrid, django-allauth

I used django cookiecutter to initialize my project. I am using **sendgrid_backend.SendgridBackend** as my email backend. I can send emails now with sendgrid but I would like to use my sendgrid template instead of the template provided by django allauth.

Here is the adapters.py provided by allauth

```
from typing import Any
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter
from allauth.socialaccount.adapter import DefaultSocialAccountAdapter
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpRequest


class AccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def is_open_for_signup(self, request: HttpRequest):
        return getattr(settings, "ACCOUNT_ALLOW_REGISTRATION", True)


class SocialAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):
    def is_open_for_signup(self, request: HttpRequest, sociallogin: Any):
        return getattr(settings, "ACCOUNT_ALLOW_REGISTRATION", True)
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are using allauth to send email you can overcome the problem by doing this
just download [this github repo](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth.git) and navigate to into this folder `allauth/templates/` and paste all templates to your project templates and delete base.html present in templates.

And now navigate into folder `templates/account`  and there you will find a template called `verified_email_required.html` and edit it in what way you need

Comment: Pavan kumar, thank you for replying.. but what I wanted was to use my sendgrid templates..